# Home folder has two Desktops within it - can one be deleted?

Tags: macos

Somehow I created a second Desktop Folder and icon within my Home Folder. One Desktop has the word original following it, the second has a different icon.

Can any suggest how this happened and can I get rid of one of them?

Answer (score 3):

**The `~/Desktop` folder is the one you should keep** since it contains your actual desktop. It should be the one with Apple's Desktop folder icon on it.

The `~/Desktop (original)` (I presume the *original* is in brackets) is from Migration Assistant (and/or Time Machine) unless you manually created it yourself. You can take out files that you need and place them elsewhere, then delete the folder.

Comment: You should copy all the things inside the original Desktop to the actual current Desktop to make sure that you don't lose anything if you delete it.

Comment: And to answer your question - after removing the items from Desktop (original) just drag it to the trash